Way to find which GTM-s are using my GA property MEASUREMENT ID
I find out that if a GA property MEASUREMENT ID is used in few Google Tag Managers then DebugView of this GA property stops working for all GTM-s. Probably, except the last one where it was configured (not 100% sure).
I saw and fixed this situation for few customers.
A workaround is to delete all duplicated usages of this MEASUREMENT ID in GTM-s, then the DebugView starts to work again but with a delay in 5-10 minutes.
My question is, is there a way to find out which GTM-s are using a MEASUREMENT ID if I'm the owner of a GA Property of this MEASUREMENT ID?
I do not want to go through all GTM-s and check them manually.


DebugView is a bugged feature. It's an industry standard not to use it. To be honest, it's also not useful. We typically either use the GTM preview or one of the various analytics debugging chrome extensions.
DebugView shouldn't depend on GTMs in any way. GA is ignorant of GTM. What it should depend on is the debug flag being present in the payload, or rather in the url.
Mass actions across multiple GTM accounts can be done via Simo Ahava's GTM tools, but I'm not sure if that allows you wide search across all the containers. You could also use GTM's API to mass-export all the containers and then look through the exported files.

